# Temporarily store images and receive a URL via a web service

Tags: ios, networking, webservice-client

I'm prototyping an iPhone app for an acquaintance and there's a requirement to share an image between devices. I'm thinking of the easiest way to do this.  I know that on an iPhone I cannot send mail or text messages without user approval and I do not have a web server or server-side scripting knowledge. This leaves some third party image sharing service.

**Are there any iOS examples out there on how to temporarily upload an image to an image hosting web service (flickr, imgur?) and get a URL to the image back?** Ideally this would not require a login/password combo and can hold images for 48 hours or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Imgur API](http://api.imgur.com/) which is free as long as you're not planning to make money with your application or your application is an open-source project. It allows you to upload your images with ease.

Answer (score 1):

Look at using [Parse.com](http://parse.com), specifically the file hosting described [here](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#files/iOS)